# What is the human-readable URL of this Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, url

The URL that I see in my browser is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/groups/665545990268762/
```

But it should have a human readable URL. Something like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/EntrepreneurialMums/
```

I need to know what it is because I need to put it on a sign.
How do I find out?
And why am I seeing this number URL?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you only get a readable URL in a Facebook group if you select one. An administrator can set it under `Group Settings -> Web and Email Address`

Comment: Using a URL shortener like tinyurl or goo.gl might be better for a sign though! Although I imagine that encouraging people to search for the page will be more effective than asking them to type in any kind of URL.

Comment: @Eric_M The only issue with asking people to search for the page is that they might find a different society with a similar name and join that. In addition, if the op or anyone else looking at this question in the future accidentally makes a group such that it will not appear in search results, it could cause issues. Furthermore, I believe that asking people to google your group might not make the op/future reader look good in the eyes of their audience. Lastly, if you write down goo.gl/nameOfFBGroup, you might be less likely to remember the purpose of the link. I like goo.gl for its analytics

Answer (score 0):

I believe facebook automatically assigns groups numbers like this. If you would like it to be human readable, then I would recommend using goo.gl or any of the other popular url shorteners. (I recommend goo.gl because it allows you to track clicks, if you are logged in when the short url is created). I would recommend using this in conjunction with a qr code.